# Migrated InfoPath Workflow form (2007 to 2010) changes its behavior with extended properties

Tags: infopath, migration

I have a InfoPath form that I use in a custom Visual Studio Workflow.

I use the `CreateTaskWithContentType` activity to create task associated with the custom form.

In the workflow code, I use `CreateTaskWithContentType.ExtendedProperties` to pass values to the form :

```
myCreateTask.ExtendedProperties = new NameValueCollection  
{
   { "Param1", "Value1"},
   { "Param2", "Value2" }
};
```

Then, in the form code, I retrieve the values using (note the `ows_` prefix):

```
XPathNavigator secondDataSource = this.DataSources["ItemMetadata"].CreateNavigator();
secondDataSource.MoveToFirstChild();

string param1 =secondDataSource.GetAttribute("ows_Param1");
```

Everything was working fine on SP 2007.

However, we recently migrated the farm to SharePoint 2010. The forms has stopped to works as expected. After some digging and headache, I finally discovered than *some* parameters are prefixed with `owsextended_` while other properties are still using the prefix `ows_`.

For example, in the same task, I will have to seek for `ows_param1`, and `owsextended_param2`.

What can cause this changed behavior? What is differentiating the parameters to produces either `ows_` or `owsextended_` prefix?

**[Edit]** I forgot to mention that the itemmetadata schema is actually showing `ows_Param1` and `ows_Param2` as attributes

*Cross posted on [Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/0ffc455d-f9fa-4a99-a1e4-fdba68e2bec6)*